# Using Vimdiff to diff two things that are not local documents

Tags: vimdiff

Every now and then I want to diff two random things (like a source-code vs some code I find online).

I could obviously create two files locally and diff them, - but I was wondering if there was a way to open Vimdiff with two empty documents (not to be saved anywhere); where I could copy/paste the text in to diff them quickly and efficiently.

If I just write `vimdiff` then I just get an empty vim-editor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can diff two unwritten buffers:

- Open vim (or open a new tab in you current vim instance)
- Put your current code in one buffer or open an existing file (`:e ./mySourceFile`)
- Split your screen with `:sp` or <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
- Open a new buffer (`:e`)
- Put the new code you want to diff in this new buffer
- And make a diff between the two buffers with `:windo diffthis`
- If you update one of the buffers update the diff with `:diffupdate`
- When you're done use `:diffoff!`

See

- [`:h :diffthis`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#%3adiffthis)
- [`:h :diffupdate`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#%3adiffupdate)
- [`:h :diffoff`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#%3adiffoff)

Comment: +1 this is also useful to vimdiff two already opened copies of a file

Comment: if you use the vimdiff command to open vim you can skip the `:windo`